# How would you translate "to a fault"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

I'm not sure if it's common to say "**Generous to a fault**". Would "Generoso a una falla" be the right translation? It sounds off to me. I'm looking for Hispanic use.

Usage:

> "He was generous to a fault" : A man so generous it worked against him.

Comment: What seems to be the most common expression in a google search is the simple phrase "demasiado generoso," although @Ustanak's "pecar de generoso" is charming and idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing tht comes to my mind would be

> Demasiado generoso para su propio bien.

You could try to go with "demasiado generoso" alone, but I don't think that by itself ot has the connotations of "too much for their own good" (which would be "*para su propio bien*" in Spanish).

Similar with other possibilities like

> Se pasó de generoso
>
> Generoso en exceso / excesivamente generoso

It could just mean that he was too or very generous (going above and beyond) but not necessarily "too much for their own good".

Similarly

> generoso hasta lo nocivo / perjudicial / contraproducente

could not work that well, although they could be used. There is something tricky about "generoso" (or *kind*, *helpful*, etc.), since when you claim that it was "to a fault" you can't really tell if it was counterproductive to the person who was being helped or to the person giving help. You could go with most of these, but my preference is to go with the "demasiado X para su propio bien" expression.

Comment: Hasta lo nocivo es mi opcion favorita

Answer (score 4):

*Generoso a una falla* is not idiomatic; however, I suggest interpreting this as ***pecar de generoso*** to imply *to much generosity caused a problem.*

Comment: An excellent idiomatic choice!

Comment: @guifa Interestingly, saying *pecar de + adjective* can be extended to a myriad of choices.

Comment: that's what helps it work so well, in English we can use many different adjectives with the construction "to a fault"